# "Warning: Division by zero" en php

Tags: php

Amigos necesito ayuda con un codigo... estoy intentando modificar un template de noticias en php y me sale este error, y no logro reparar eso les dejo el mensaje y el codigo.

> Warning: Division by zero in... on line 89
>   Something is wrong in your query syntax.

```
$num_news = $mysql->num_rows();
 $num_pages = ceil($num_news / $news_per_page);

 if ($_GET['page'] != 1)
```

gracias.

Comment: ¿Ninguna de las respuestas ha sido la correcta?

Answer (score 2):

En Matemáticas y por ende en la computación la división entre cero no está definida por lo que tienes que validar que el numerador no debe ser cero y creo que por lógica de tu programa debe ser mayor a cero.

```
      if ( $news_per_page > 0)
         $num_pages = ceil($num_news / $news_per_page);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo verifica que tu variable no sea cero:

```
if ( $news_per_page != 0)
    $num_pages = ceil($num_news / $news_per_page);
else
    {
       // hacer algo diferente, poner un valor por defecto por ejemplo:
       $news_per_page = 10;
       $num_pages = ceil($num_news / $news_per_page);
    }
```

Al ser un `warning` no significa que la variable sea cero, pero es una posibilidad y por ello se indica que lo prevengas.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías de definir por default cuantos resultados quieres ver por página, por eso es la divisón

```
$news_per_page = 10;// Número de resultados por página
$num_pages = ceil($num_news / $news_per_page);// Número de páginas
```

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje de aviso indica el problema:

> Warning: Division by zero in... on line 89 Something is wrong in your
>   query syntax.

la variable  `$news_per_page` tiene un valor de cero!

Debes inicializar con un valor correcto  `$news_per_page` ya que deseas obtener el numero de paginas de acuerdo al numero de noticias por página.

**Cuantas noticias por página deseas? este valor debe ser :  `$news_per_page`**, esta variable no debe tener el valor de 0.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes validar que el valor de la variable `$news_per_page` sea distinto cero (`0`) utilizando el [operador ternario](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary) (`?:`).

Ejemplo:

```
 // Si $news_per_page fuera cero (0), false o vacío (""), entonces se asignara 1 
 $var = $var ? $var : 10;
```